# Angular sub-child router lazy loading

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Edit: still haven't solved, I'm using angular 9 rc7 btw

Many hours passed and I still don't understand whats wrong, thats my repo where you can check directly - https://github.com/Mautriz/angular-boilerplate/tree/feature/cypress

I have a root router, a lazy-loaded "pages" module, and the pages module has many lazy loaded children

```js
// App
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "page-not-found",
    component: NotFoundComponent
  },
  {
    path: "",
    loadChildren: () => import("./pages/pages.module").then(m => m.PagesModule),
    data: { preload: true }
  },

  {
    path: "**",
    redirectTo: "page-not-found"
  }
];
// Pages
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "statistics",
        loadChildren: () =>
          import("./statistics/statistics.module").then(
            m => m.StatisticsModule
          ),
        data: { preload: true }
      },
      {
        path: "",
        loadChildren: () =>
          import("./homepage/homepage.module").then(m => m.HomepageModule),
        data: { preload: true }
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

The problem is that if I check chromes request, I can only see the "pages-module" lazily loaded, but can't see the single pages ones (even tho they work)

Why are they not lazily loaded ? Am I missing something? I'm trying to implement a custom strategy and that's preventing me from understanding if it's working or not

EDIT: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G56zx.png
The submodules are not getting generated appearently, and I don't know why

Comment: While serving the app, do you see the chunks getting generated for the single pages ones?

Comment: Just checked, no they aren't getting generated :/ https://i.imgur.com/AbW6v7j.png

Answer (score 1):

You seem to not have configured the `HomePageRoutingModule` and `StatisticsRoutingModule`. Hence the issue.

Please configure those modules as well to see chunks of them getting generated.

Here is how you would do that for `HomepageRoutingModule`:

```
import { HomepageComponent } from "./homepage.component";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";

const routes: Routes = [{ path: "", component: HomepageComponent }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomepageRoutingModule {}
```

Similarly for `StatisticsRoutingModule`, you'd do it like this:

```
import { StatisticsComponent } from "./statistics.component";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: StatisticsComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class StatisticsRoutingModule {}
```

Seems to be getting generated for me:

[image]

> Here's the [**GitHub Repo**](https://github.com/SiddAjmera/lazy-loading-child-routes) for the Code that I have for your ref.
>
> Here's the [**Sample Working Code Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/github/SiddAjmera/lazy-loading-child-routes) for your ref.

Comment: **PS:** You won't see the modules getting downloaded on lazily and on-demand on StackBlitz coz they have some really complex algorithm that preloads even the lazily-loaded modules. In order to see it lazily-load modules on-demand, you'll have to check by cloning the repo that I've attached with the answer. Just letting you know about it upfront :)

Comment: hey man, thanks for the answer, I already had those modules configured with router and forChild tho, that's the repository https://github.com/Mautriz/angular-boilerplate/tree/feature/cypress. Don't mind all the random stuff, I'm using this project to learn

Comment: I think these additional changes that you've made is what's breaking the code chunking. I also see that you've used some `CustomPreloadStrategy` as your `preloadStrategy` in the `AppRoutingModule`. That could be causing the issue. BTW, I was not able to run your App on my local as I kept getting **core.js:6406 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded** error

Comment: It worked to me using both npm and yarn on a different computer (having just downloaded it), have you used the ng serve as "npm run ng serve"? might be because you are using a different angular version (i'm using 9.0.0-rc7

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, it was just a simple importing mistake in the end.
I had imported the homepage module in the pages module (even tho the lazy loading in routing was correct)

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    PagesRoutingModule,
    HomePageModule, // MISTAKE!!!
    SharedModule,
    TranslateModule.forChild({ loader: TranslationLoader })
  ],
  declarations: [LayoutComponent]
})
export class PagesModule {}
```